# Electron Browser Window won't open

Tags: electron

When I am executing npm command npm start it shows only this not opening an electron browser window.

> firstdesktopapp@1.0.0 start E:\NodeJS Projects\ElectronJs\FirstDesktopAPp
>
> electron .

here is my package.json code

```
{
  "name": "firstdesktopapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "First Desktop App on Electron",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
 },
 "author": "Makhmoor Rehman",
 "license": "NoN",
 "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^4.0.0-nightly.20181010"
 }
}
```

and here is my app.js code

```
const electron = require("electron");
const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

const {app, BrowserWindow} = electron;

let mainWindow;

// Listen for app to be ready
app.on("ready", function() {
    // Create new window
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({});

    //load html into window
    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
        protocol: "file:",
        slashes: true,
    }));

});
```

I have installed the latest version of electron and nodejs, I have a dell laptop and os Windows 10 64bit.

After killing the process of electron I am getting this.

> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! errno 1
>
> npm ERR! firstdesktopapp@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
>
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
>
> npm ERR!
>
> npm ERR! Failed at the firstdesktopapp@1.0.0 start script.
>
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>
> logging output ab             ove.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\makhm\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-10-31T01_10_09_481Z-debug.log

And in the **debug** file I am getting this

nfo it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'E:\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'start' ]

2 info using npm@6.4.1

3 info using node@v11.0.0

4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

5 info lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~prestart: firstdesktopapp@1.0.0

6 info lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~start: firstdesktopapp@1.0.0

7 verbose lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

8 verbose lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~start: PATH: 
E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;E:\NodeJS Projects\ElectronJs\FirstDesktopAPp\node_modules.bin;C:\Users\makhm\bin;E:\Git\mingw64\bin;E:\Git\usr\local\bin;E:\Git\usr\bin;E:\Git\usr\bin;E:\Git\mingw64\bin;E:\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\makhm\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\SKYPE\PHONE;C:\xampp\php;F:\PuTTY;C:\xamppp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;E:\Git\cmd;E:\nodejs;C:\Users\makhm\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\makhm\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\makhm\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin;C:\Users\makhm\AppData\Roaming\npm;E:\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;E:\Git\usr\bin\core_perl

9 verbose lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~start: CWD: E:\NodeJS Projects\ElectronJs\FirstDesktopAPp

10 silly lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'electron .' ]

11 silly lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null

12 info lifecycle firstdesktopapp@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script

13 verbose stack Error: firstdesktopapp@1.0.0 start: `electron .`

13 verbose stack Exit status 1

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter. (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)

13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess. (E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)

13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)

13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)

13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)

14 verbose pkgid firstdesktopapp@1.0.0

15 verbose cwd E:\NodeJS Projects\ElectronJs\FirstDesktopAPp

16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134

17 verbose argv "E:\nodejs\node.exe" "E:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"

18 verbose node v11.0.0

19 verbose npm  v6.4.1

20 error code ELIFECYCLE

21 error errno 1

22 error firstdesktopapp@1.0.0 start: `electron .`

22 error Exit status 1

23 error Failed at the firstdesktopapp@1.0.0 start script.

23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

"

Comment: Hmm, I get a perfect fine window with your code with the latest stable electron version 3.0.6 and with the version you used. There seems to be more to the problem than a coding error. What OS do you use? Windows 10?

Comment: I use win10 64bit

Comment: Same thing is happening to me, but I get no errors, just run the start command and nothing happens. Same OS too, Win10 64bit

Comment: @JB06  [link](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues/155) this might help, I have checked every solution in this issue not work for me, Check solutions from here maybe you will find the solution here.

Comment: @JB06 and I am getting an error after terminating electron from the task manager

Comment: I don't believe that Electron supports that version of Node. Try downgrading to 10.11

Comment: Thanks @pushkin It worked for me after installing the 10.13 version of nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the latest version of nodejs 11 that's why that was not working when I install the 10.11 version it worked thanks for @pushkin.